# npm login with --scope doesn't seem to work

Tags: npm

Is the `--scope` param broken? When I run
`npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=@<my-org>` it doesn't add any scope definition to .npmrc

.npmrc after the command above:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<MY-TOKEN>
```

Then, when trying to download private packages it defaults to npm official registry, which returns 404 for obvious reasons.

I was able to make it work by also running:
`npm config set @<my-org>:registry https://npm.pkg.github.com/`, which resulted on the following .npmrc:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<MY-TOKEN>
@<MY-ORG>:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

But I'm curious as why npm login itself doesn't work as expected. My understanding is that it should add the scope definition automatically, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that it should add the scope definition automatically, right?

Yes, I have the same understanding based on this [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry) stating

> You can associate a scope with a registry at login

I looked further and this behaviour has been reported as a bug. There was an [issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3292) filed for npm v7.8.0 with the [fix](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/3383) released as part of v7.17.0.

That said, I encountered this problem using npm v7.20.3 and I used the same workaround as you. Currently, there has been another [issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4098) filed for npm v8.1.4.

According to one commenter in the GitHub issues, the behaviour works as expected in npm v7.0.10, so the answer to "Is the `--scope` param broken?" depends on the version of npm you're using.